# Environment health has been set to RED even instance and system health check are ok

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk to deploy a single instance environment to AWS. All went good. I tested the auto scaling by terminating the instance, another instance was created to satisfy auto-scaling settings for single instance environment (Min: 1, Max: 1).

After the new instance is up and running, there are two issues:

1. The site is still not accessible. I fixed this by associating the Elastic IP to the new instance, for some reason it did not associate EIP automatically. This fixed the site issue.
2. The Elastic Beanstalk  health to RED – “Environment health has been set to RED” even after fixing #1.

Everything is working except the annoying environment status.

How to fix this?

I checked the EC2 instance health status check (both system and instance) all are green and good. 
I also tried restarting the instance but still Elastic Beanstalk health status is RED.
This is a .NET Web API application published via visual studio 2017 Elastic Beanstalk

I expect AWS Elastic Beanstalk status should be back to green since instance is healthy and site is running.

When I attempt to publish updates of the application a message shows that the deployment fails but I checked the application all the changes are applied successfully... probably because of Beanstalk RED health status that causes it to show failed deployment...

Comment: I am having same issue. ELB instance seems to be working fine but health status is red.